# Returning an array from function

Tags: c, pointers, return

I am writing a function which takes in the integer value and the pointer to a character.
the function converts the integer value into binary and stores it in the char pointer.
the char pointer is 16 bytes long.

Snippet of code:

```
void int2bin(u_int16_t addr_IP, char *Binary)
{
    int count;
    printf("IP1add = %d \n", Binary);
    for (count = 0; count < 16; count++) {
        if(addr_IP>0)
            *(Binary + 15-count) = addr_IP & 0x1 ? '1':'0';
        else
            *(Binary + 15-count) = '0';

          addr_IP>>=1;
    }   
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    u_int16_t senderIP_16[], u_int16_t receiverIP_16[];
    char  sender_IP_hi[16], sender_IP_low[16];
    int2bin(senderIP_16[0], &sender_IP_hi);
    int2bin(senderIP_16[1], &sender_IP_low);
}
```

In the first call to the function, it returns correct values. But in the second pass, the value of first pass is appended to the second pass, i.e length of `sender_IP_low` becomes 32.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you printing with printf() ?

Comment: Few things: 1/ what is that comma in the first line of `main`? 2/ why the length of arrays are not specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're printing `sender_IP_low` as a string, and since it is not null-terminated, the print routine continues to print the adjacent buffer, `sender_IP_hi`. And you're probably just lucky that the print routine finds a zero and stops before a segmentation fault.

One quick fix is:

```
void int2bin(u_int16_t addr_IP, char *Binary) {
    ...

    Binary[16] = 0; // terminate the string before returning
}

...

char  sender_IP_hi[17], sender_IP_low[17]; // +1 for null terminator
```

Although, there are a few other things that could be fixed in your implementation, I just wanted to focus on an answer to your original question.

Comment: Thanks Ates! It worked! You mentioned about fixing other things in the code. Could you pls tell me what else could be done to improve the implementation.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ritesh Banka: You could simply increment the `Binary` pointer instead of offsetting it with a counter; and use a bitmask that starts at 0x8000 and gets right-shifted each iteration so that you can output bits hi-to-low instead of using the `15 - count` trick. Anyway, your code is functionally correct and what I'm suggesting is just a matter of personal taste regarding style.

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing the arrays with printf():

```
void int2bin(u_int16_t addr_IP, char *Binary)
{
    int count;
    printf("IP1add = %d \n", Binary);
    for (count = 0; count < 16; count++) {
        if(addr_IP>0)
            *(Binary + 15-count) = addr_IP & 0x1 ? '1':'0';
        else
            *(Binary + 15-count) = '0';

          addr_IP>>=1;
    }   
    // Put the NULL char in the last position
    Binary[16] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    u_int16_t senderIP_16[], u_int16_t receiverIP_16[];
    // One more char for storing the terminator character
    char  sender_IP_hi[17], sender_IP_low[17];
    int2bin(senderIP_16[0], &sender_IP_hi);
    int2bin(senderIP_16[1], &sender_IP_low);
}
```